# Search backward in visual studio code from current position

Tags: visual-studio-code

Suppose I have a very loooong file with all my libraries and its functions (can't change it, that's what I have to work with), all in one file, e.g.:

```
    [library1
    function 1
    blablablah1
    
    
    [library2
...
    function 2
    blablablah2
```

I want to find the closest [library...] line, to guess which library contains my current cursor line:

For example, if I have the cursor in the line "blablablah2", and do a search (ctrl+f), and start typing "[lib", the cursor immediately goes to "[library1" because it always start searching from the beginning of the file. I want that, when I start typing, the cursor don't start moving until I press the "up" arrow to search backwards... so I find the [library2] line

Thanks in advance,

Roger

Answer (score 2):

Disable this setting:

`Editor > Find: Cursor Move On Type`

> // Controls whether the cursor should jump to find matches while
> typing.   "editor.find.cursorMoveOnType": false,

Now the cursor will not jump to matches as you type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by).

Add this to your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+f6",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": {
      "ask": true,
      "properties": ["prev", "start"]
    }
  }
```

You enter a regular expression (escape a few characters if needed).